# Curl terminal command syntax from Applescript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line

I want to execute a `curl` command in Applescript that does the following ([per this SE question/answer](https://superuser.com/a/1054803/471181)):

https://superuser.com/a/1054803/471181

> ...Do an `HTTP POST` of the ***contents*** (as a string) of a local file located at `path/to/my-file.txt` to a URL endpoint at `http://example.com/API`.

The correct `curl` command for that is the following:

Terminal

```
curl -d "data=@~/path/to/my-file.txt" https://example.com/API
```

[Following the answers in this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4599614?tstart=0), I tried the following Applescript command:

AppleScript

```
do shell script "curl -d data=@~/path/to/my-file.txt https://example.com/API"
```

The result I expect is to see the contents of *my-file.txt* POSTed to the API endpoint at `https://example.com/API` with the key `data`.

However, the actual result I see at the endpoint with the key `data` is the following string:

API.data

```
"@~/path/to/my-file.txt
```

In other words, instead of POSTing the contents of the file, it's POSTing the literal path to the file as a string.

### Question

**What is the correct Applescript command syntax?**

Other unsuccessful attempts:

AppleScript

```
do shell script "curl -d data=\@~/path/to/my-file.txt https://example.com/API"
do shell script "curl -d \"data=@~/path/to/my-file.txt\" https://example.com/API"
do shell script "curl -d 'data=@~/path/to/my-file.txt' https://example.com/API"
```

On list to try:

1. Use the fully qualified pathname to my-file.txt, do not use ~.
2. Escape the " in the data= option, e.g.: do shell script "curl -d \"data=@~/path/to/my-file.txt\" https://example.com/API"

Comment: @klanomath: That gets the same result.

Comment: Would https://example.com/API really work or is it just an example? or do you have a test api somewhere?

Comment: Two thing I can think of. 1. Use the fully qualified pathname to `my-file.txt`, do not use `~`. 2. Escape the `"` in the `data=` option, e.g.: `do shell script "curl -d \"data=@~/path/to/my-file.txt\" https://example.com/API"`